# I want to factor/factorize a complicated polynomial of degree 8. I have guessed a solution too but I need to tweak it a bit

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, mathematical-physics

So I want to factorize a polynomial $\Theta(x)$ which is defined below:
$$\Theta(x) = (768h^8x^8-3072h^8x^7-768h^6w^2x^6+4992h^8x^6-768Hh^6x^6+2304h^6w^2x^5-4224h^8x^5+2304Hh^6x^5+288h^4w^4x^4-3264h^6w^2x^4+576Hh^4w^2x^4+1968h^8x^4-2688Hh^6x^4+192H^2h^4x^4-576h^4w^4x^3+2688h^6w^2x^3-1152Hh^4w^2x^3-480h^8x^3+1536Hh^6x^3-384H^2h^4x^3+336h^4w^4x^2-816h^6w^2x^2+672Hh^4w^2x^2-96h^8x^2+144H^2h^6x^2+48Hh^6x^2+224H^2h^4x^2-48h^4w^4x-144h^6w^2x-96Hh^4w^2x+144h^8x-144H^2h^6x-432Hh^6x-32H^2h^4x+3w^8+12Hw^6-6h^4w^4+12H^2w^4+84h^6w^2-12Hh^4w^2-36h^8+36H^2h^6+120Hh^6-4H^2h^4)$$

My guess for the factorize version of this polynomial $\Theta(x)$ is writtien below:
$$3h^8(2x+\frac{w}{h}-1)(2x+\frac{w}{h}-2)(2x-\frac{w}{h})(2x-\frac{w}{h}-1)(2x-1/2+\sqrt{(\frac{w}{h}-1/2)^2+\frac{2H}{h^2}})(2x-3/2+\sqrt{(\frac{w}{h}-1/2)^2+\frac{2H}{h^2}})(2x-1/2-\sqrt{(\frac{w}{h}-1/2)^2+\frac{2H}{h^2}})(2x-3/2-\sqrt{(\frac{w}{h}-1/2)^2+\frac{2H}{h^2}})$$

So,  Now If I now expand the above written product the result I get is this:
$$768h^8x^8-3072h^8x^7-768h^6w^2x^6+768h^7wx^6+4992h^8x^6-768Hh^6x^6+2304h^6w^2x^5-2304h^7wx^5-4224h^8x^5+2304Hh^6x^5+288h^4w^4x^4-576h^5w^3x^4-2400h^6w^2x^4+576Hh^4w^2x^4+2688h^7wx^4-576Hh^5wx^4+1968h^8x^4-2688Hh^6x^4+192H^2h^4x^4-576h^4w^4x^3+1152h^5w^3x^3+960h^6w^2x^3-1152Hh^4w^2x^3-1536h^7wx^3+1152Hh^5wx^3-480h^8x^3+1536Hh^6x^3-384H^2h^4x^3-48h^2w^6x^2+144h^3w^5x^2+264h^4w^4x^2-144Hh^2w^4x^2-768h^5w^3x^2+288Hh^3w^3x^2-24h^6w^2x^2+672Hh^4w^2x^2-96H^2h^2w^2x^2+432h^7wx^2-816Hh^5wx^2+96H^2h^3wx^2+48h^8x^2-432Hh^6x^2+240H^2h^4x^2+48h^2w^6x-144h^3w^5x+24h^4w^4x+144Hh^2w^4x+192h^5w^3x-288Hh^3w^3x-72h^6w^2x-96Hh^4w^2x+96H^2h^2w^2x-48h^7wx+240Hh^5wx-96H^2h^3wx+48Hh^6x-48H^2h^4x+3w^8-12hw^7+6h^2w^6+12Hw^6+24h^3w^5-36Hhw^5-21h^4w^4+12H^2w^4-12h^5w^3+60Hh^3w^3-24H^2hw^3+12h^6w^2-12Hh^4w^2-12H^2h^2w^2-24Hh^5w+24H^2h^3w$$

So, you can see that the expansion of factorize version (guessed) is somewhat same to the polynomial $\Theta(x)$ that I want to factor. Now my problem is what or how should I make changes to the factorize version that I guessed so that my expansion of factorize version mathches the polynomial $\Theta(x)$.

So If I know subract the two expressions this is what I get
$$(-768h^7wx^6)+2304h^7wx^5+(576h^5w^3-864h^6w^2+(576Hh^5-2688h^7)w)x^4+((-1152h^5w^3)+1728h^6w^2+(1536h^7-1152Hh^5)w)x^3+(48h^2w^6-144h^3w^5+(72h^4+144Hh^2)w^4+(768h^5-288Hh^3)w^3+(96H^2h^2-792h^6)w^2+((-432h^7)+816Hh^5-96H^2h^3)w-144h^8+(144H^2+480H)h^6-16H^2h^4)x^2+((-48h^2w^6)+144h^3w^5+((-72h^4)-144Hh^2)w^4+(288Hh^3-192h^5)w^3+((-72h^6)-96H^2h^2)w^2+(48h^7-240Hh^5+96H^2h^3)w+144h^8+((-144H^2)-480H)h^6+16H^2h^4)x+12hw^7-6h^2w^6+(36Hh-24h^3)w^5+15h^4w^4+(12h^5-60Hh^3+24H^2h)w^3+(72h^6+12H^2h^2)w^2+(24Hh^5-24H^2h^3)w-36h^8+(36H^2+120H)h^6-4H^2h^4$$

So I got this polynomial $\Theta(x)$ by doing commutator algebra. I computed some coefficients and a Casimir operator from that algebra which I know are all correct. Then I had to substitute these coeffcients and casimir operator which I caluclated using commutator algebra into a predifined function $\Theta(x)$ which is defined in terms of that Coefficients and Casimir operator. So that's how I got $\Theta(x)$. To carry out further analysis I have to write it in factorize form

Comment: wow, that's a monster of an expression! I doubt that many people would have patience to even read through that. Maybe you can highlight the differences between the first and the last expression?

Comment: Where is the first expression coming from ? How did you guess any of the factors ? Please clarify. Cheers and, by the way, **Welcome to the site !**

Comment: Compare both expressions for $x=0$ first, i.e., $\Theta(0)$.

Comment: So, I got this polynomial by doing some commutator algebra. I evaluated some coefficients and Casimir operator from that algebra. Then substitute that into a function which was defined in terms of that coefficients

Comment: I guessed the factorized form on the basis of the other authors paper that worked on the similar thing and got the polynomial of order '8'. They also wrote it down in the factorized form in the last to do some analysis. So, I played around with there factorized form to get this product form.

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed as follows.

a) simplify notation
put for instance
$$
2x = y\quad {w \over h} - {1 \over 2} = a\quad 2{H \over {h^{\,2} }} = b^{\,2} 
$$
and get the polynomial in $y$ and two parameters
$$
p(y,a,b) = 3h^{\,8} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^8 {f_{\,k} \left( {a,b} \right)y^{\,k} }  = 3h^{\,8} \prod\limits_{j = 1}^8 {\left( {y - r_{\,j} (a,b)} \right)} 
$$

where the roots are your attempted roots.

b) pass to leading coeff. $1$
$$
q(y,a,b) = {{p(y,a,b)} \over {3h^{\,8} }} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^8 {f_{\,k} \left( {a,b} \right)y^{\,k} }  = \prod\limits_{j = 1}^8 {\left( {y - r_{\,j} (a,b)} \right)} 
$$

c) check for $y=r_j(a,b)$
check each supposed root to give $0$ when replaced for $y$ in the sum version;
take note of the valid and invalid roots;

d) divide by the valid roots
perform long division to get a a polynomial of reduced degree, containing only the invalid roots.

e) check for $y=0$ in the reduced "invalid" polynomial
you should get
$$
f_{\,0} \left( {a,b} \right) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \prod\limits_{j = 1}^n {\left( {y - r_{\,j} (a,b)} \right)} 
$$
try and see what goes wrong, also by putting some easy values (0,1, ..) for $a,b$;
try and get some other valid root and repeat from d).